# How do I make the DataGridView show the selected row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll, selected

I need to force the `DataGridView` to show the selected `row`.

In short, I have a `textbox` that changes the `DGV` selection based on what is typed into the `textbox`.  When this happens, the selection changes to the matching `row`.

Unfortunately if the selected `row` is out of the view, I have to manually scroll down to find the selection.  Does anyone know how to force the `DGV` to show the selected `row`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the CurrentCell property, the DGV will scroll to make it visible.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can set:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx) on this property.

Answer (score 61):

This one scrolls to the selected row without put it on top.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0];
```

Comment: Definitely more user-friendly than `DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`, thanks!

Comment: Unlike FirstDisplayedScrollingRowInde, this also moves the row arrow to the correct row, selects row, and unselects any other row.

Comment: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]`

Comment: However, if the first column has been hidden, this WILL throw an exception.

Comment: Note that if the `.CurrentCell` is *already* the one that it's being changed to, it won't scroll it into view even if it's not currently visible. You can fix that by setting `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;` before setting it to the actual cell.

Answer (score 29):

Consider also this code (uses the from competent_tech suggested way):

```
private static void EnsureVisibleRow(DataGridView view, int rowToShow)
{
    if (rowToShow >= 0 && rowToShow < view.RowCount)
    {
        var countVisible = view.DisplayedRowCount(false);
        var firstVisible = view.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        if (rowToShow < firstVisible)
        {
            view.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowToShow;
        }
        else if (rowToShow >= firstVisible + countVisible)
        {
            view.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowToShow - countVisible + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A very functional answer...worthy of far more votes.

Comment: I agree, so I have upvoted it! It works better than any of the other solutions.

Comment: Works great - I made rowToShow opptional and set it to the last row if not set by the caller. Now it scrolls to the bottom by default. Could add another signature to give it a better name.

Comment: Thanks. This works a lot better than other answers. Tip for other users: I modified it a bit to pass in firstVisible because my list was also being refreshed before I needed to call EnsureVisibleRow (after refreshing the DataGridView contents, FirstDiaplayedScrollingRowIndex was always reset to zero so I had to save it before the refresh)

Comment: Small bug: the condition should be: `else if (rowToShow >= firstVisible + countVisible - 1)` (I just wrote the same solution because I missed this reply!)

Comment: Hello @P.W., please check again. For example, if the first visible row is 3 and the window height is 5, 8 is the first invisible row (3 + 5). 

So we have to do when:
`rowToShow  >=  firstVisible + countVisible (>= 8)`
or
`rowToShow   > firstVisible + countVisible - 1 (> 7)`

Comment: Hi @Georg, yes you are right, sorry about that (and thanks). Maybe I confused `>=` with `>` at that time. I will go correct my code, despite it is working fine with this condition as well ;)

Answer (score 11):

Just put that line after the selecting the row:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Comment: Missed it by a single minute!

Answer (score 1):

```
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(searchString))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
if (rowIndex >= 0)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[visibleColumnIndex, rowIndex];
}
```

visibleColumnIndex - selected cell must be visible

Answer (score 1):

Please note that setting **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** when your DataGridView is not enabled will scroll the list to desired row, but scrollbar will not reflect its position. Simpliest solution is re-enabling and disabling your DGV.

```
dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

// This works, it's case sensitive and finds the first occurrence of search

```
    private bool FindInGrid(string search)
    {
        bool results = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
        {
            if (row.DataBoundItem != null)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains(search))
                    {
                        dgvData.CurrentCell = cell;
                        dgvData.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = cell.RowIndex;
                        results = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (results == true)
                        break;
                }
                if (results == true)
                    break;
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this:

`dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0];`

will only work if the first column is visible. If it is hidden, you'll get an exception. This is safer:

`var column = dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null ?
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex :
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[iNextHighlight].Cells[column];`

This will reset the selection without scrolling if the target row is already on screen. It also preserves the current column choice which can matter in cases where you've allowed inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

I made the next search function it works wel for scrolling selections in display.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
  string strSearch = txtSearch.Text.ToUpper();
  int iIndex = -1;
  int iFirstFoundRow = -1;
  bool bFound = false;
  if (strSearch != "")
  {
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    /*  Select All Rows Starting With The Search string in row.cells[1] =
    second column. The search string can be 1 letter till a complete line
    If The dataGridView MultiSelect is set to true this will highlight 
    all found rows. If The dataGridView MultiSelect is set to false only 
    the last found row will be highlighted. Or if you jump out of the  
    foreach loop the first found row will be highlighted.*/

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
     if ((row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToUpper()).IndexOf(strSearch) == 0)
     {
       iIndex = row.Index;
       if(iFirstFoundRow == -1)  // First row index saved in iFirstFoundRow
       {
         iFirstFoundRow = iIndex;
       }
       dataGridView1.Rows[iIndex].Selected = true; // Found row is selected
       bFound = true; // This is needed to scroll de found rows in display
       // break; //uncomment this if you only want the first found row.
     }
   }
   if (bFound == false)
   {
     dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); // Nothing found clear all Highlights.
   }
   else
   {
     // Scroll found rows in display
     dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = iFirstFoundRow; 
   }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the one I use.