# Scroll from selected row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i created a code where an item is searched in the datagridviw and when a user hits enter or down key the focus is set to the datagridview , I want the scroll staart from the selected row but it is starting from the last selected row.

my code :

```
  Private Function FindItems(ByVal strSearchString As String) As Boolean
    dgvsearchitem.ClearSelection()
 For Each myRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvsearchitem.Rows
        For Each myCell As DataGridViewCell In myRow.Cells
            If InStr(myCell.Value.ToString, strSearchString,CompareMethod.Text) Then
                myRow.Selected = True
                Return True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return False

End Function
 Private Sub txtitemsearch_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtitemsearch.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab) And txtiname.Text <> "" Then
        dgvsearchitem.Focus()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437916/how-do-i-make-the-datagridview-show-the-selected-row the code in vb.net is exactly the same... `dgvsearchitem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = myRow.Index`

Comment: still not working , not affected the program

Comment: and where exactly did you place that piece of code?

Comment: after
dgvsearchitem.Focus()

Comment: shouldn't that have given you an error?? anyway if you wanna place it there do `dgvsearchitem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvsearchitem.SelectedRows(0).Index`

Comment: not giving any error but
even if i m putting dgvsearchitem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex =2
it  is scrolling from the selected index of previous search