# Allow pixel scrolling for windows form c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

Is it possible to scroll per-pixel in a datagridview object in Windows Form? If yes, which property have I to change?

Comment: What do you mean about "per-pixel"? If you want to go to next row, you can override the scroll events for showing selected rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437916/how-do-i-make-the-datagridview-show-the-selected-row

Answer (score 1):

There are no such options in standard DataGridView out-of-the -box, so you can only take a look at some third-party solutions...

However, if your DataGridView contains a few rows(less than 2000), you can use an approach with enclosing the DataGridView into a scrollable container/panel, setting its height outside the boundary of the container and then using the container's scroll bars.