# Change C# Datagridview row selection base on textbox input value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to change the datagridview row selection base on the value inputted in textbox with suggestappend. My autocompletestringcollection was fetched on my datagrid column reference.

**Code for autocompletestringcollection**

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection referenceCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

int indexOfYourColumn = 1;

                IList list = dgvScriptures.Rows;
                referenceCollection.Clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)list[i];
                    data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString();
                    referenceCollection.Add(data.ToString());
                }
```

**When type in textbox, value is appended but the datagridview selection was not changed**

```
private void txtSearchReference_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtSearchReference.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                txtSearchReference.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtSearchReference.AutoCompleteCustomSource = referenceCollection;

                if (txtSearchReference.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    int rowIndex = -1;
                    DataGridViewRow row = dgvScriptures.Rows
                        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearchReference.Text))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    rowIndex = row.Index;

                    dgvScriptures.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception autocomplete)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(autocomplete.ToString());
            }
            
        }
```

[UI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHP3G.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the DataGridView show the selected row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437916/how-do-i-make-the-datagridview-show-the-selected-row)

Comment: I will try to read it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'll need to change

```
dgvScriptures.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

To

```
dgvScriptures.CurrentCell = dgvScriptures[1,rowIndex];
```

The 1 being the column you searched/built your autocomplete list from

Comment: ```dgvScriptures.CurrentCell = dgvScriptures.Cells[rowIndex,1];``` 
DataGridView does not contain the definition for Cells and no accessible extension method Cells